# How write even and odd press of button in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a problem:

I need show info (for example, "text 1") if the button was pressed first time. If the button was pressed second time, I would like to show"text 2". And after third time - "text 1", etc.

How can I do it in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var buttonTappedCount : Int = 0
func buttonTapped(){
    ++buttonTappedCount

    if(buttonTappedCount % 2 == 0) {
        button.text = "1"
    } else {
        button.text = "2"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Swift version.

```
public class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var count = 0

    // Connect these up on your storyboard
    @IBOutlet var button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!


    @IBAction func pressButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        if ( count % 2 ) == 0 {
            label.text = "text 1"
        }
        else {
            label.text = "text 2"
        }
        ++count
    }
}
```